# nginx ignoring location with hyphens

Tags: nginx

I am having a problem with nginx "location" directive and regular expressions.

I want to have a location match a url that begins with "/user-profile".

The problem is that nginx does not match that, however if I change the config and try with userprofile (i.e. no hyphen) it works like a charm.

I think that there is regexp related problem, but can't get my head around it.

My current config is:

```
location ^~ /user-profile {
    proxy_pass http://remotesites;
}
```

And I've also tried with:

```
location ^~ /user\-profile {
    proxy_pass http://remotesites;
}
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks!

Comment: `location ^~ /user-profile` on its own works fine, your problem is caused either by other parts of your nginx configuration or upstream.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
location ^~ "/user-profile" {
proxy_pass http://remotesites;
}
```

Comment: This just saved me countless hours I'm sure. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
location ~ ^/user-profile {
    proxy_pass http://remotesites;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember if your location is not working as expected in Nginx, as I just spent ages finding out:

```
location /fred-plus {
   root /var/me
}
```

/fred will be APPENDED to become ...   /var/me/fred-plus

but ...

```
location /fred-plus {
    alias /var/me
}
```

/fred-plus will REPLACED to become ...   /var/me

Just spent a fair while sorting this out after coming from Apache land.

I've included the hyphen as it was the red herring that was not the problem in my case.